# Is it possible name labels sequentially in visual studio and visual c++?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

In my application, I have 4 boxes/labels and I want to fill the boxes one at a time and I have tried doing something like this:

```
label1->Text = Convert::ToString(array[0]);

label2->Text = Convert::ToString(array[1]);

label3->Text = Convert::ToString(array[2]);

label4->Text = Convert::ToString(array[3]);
```

Running this line of code sequentially will fill up all the boxes instantly when I run the program, is there anyway to make it so that it fills the four textboxes one at a time like an animation?

Comment: Do mean to have a slight pause between each text showing up? If so, you could use [`System::Threading::Thread::Sleep`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to pause between each `Text = ..` line .. (though if you do this in your main GUI thread then your GUI thread will be paused as well, i.e. it will appear unresponsive) ..

Comment: Hi, very sorry for later eply, but I have tried using Sleep(#), but it also doens't work, is this somehow different?

Comment: I want it to appear one at a time on the gui, but even doing that it still appears all at once on gui.

Comment: If you're referring to the [`WinAPI Sleep`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, then no, it's functionally equivalent to it's .NET counterpart .. but if your sleeping in your GUI thread then it will still appear 'all at once' because you're pausing the `draw` functions of the form from happening (which is what setting the text does). Try putting an [`Application::DoEvents()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) before or after the `Sleep`